# Additional Where Fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to add another WHERE query to this but am not having any joy at all.

I have a form with three fields: price, min_price and max_price.

I have added this line:

```
WHERE 'price' BETWEEN 'property_min_price' AND 'property_max_price'
```

Which seems logical to me but its not working. Any tips? Thanks.

```
/**
* Set the Query
*/
private function setQuery()
{
    $sql = "
        SELECT 
        p.post_title AS title,
        p.ID AS id," .
        $this->sqlFieldVars() . "
        lat.meta_value AS latitude,
        lng.meta_value AS longitude,
        ( " . $this->query_data['diameter'] . " * acos( cos( radians(@origlat) ) * cos( radians( lat.meta_value ) ) 
        * cos( radians( lng.meta_value ) - radians(@origlng) ) + sin( radians(@origlat) ) * sin(radians(lat.meta_value)) ) )
        AS distance
        FROM " . $this->query_data['post_table'] . " AS p
        LEFT JOIN " . $this->query_data['meta_table'] . " AS lat
        ON p.ID = lat.post_id AND lat.meta_key = '" . $this->query_data['lat_field'] . "'
        LEFT JOIN " . $this->query_data['meta_table'] . " AS lng
        ON p.ID = lng.post_id AND lng.meta_key = '" . $this->query_data['lng_field'] . "'" . 
        $this->sqlFieldJoins() . "      
        WHERE lat.meta_value
            BETWEEN @origlat - (@distance / @dist_unit)
            AND @origlat + (@distance / @dist_unit)
        AND lng.meta_value
            BETWEEN @origlng - (@distance / (@dist_unit * cos(radians(@origlat))))
            AND @origlng + (@distance / (@dist_unit * cos(radians(@origlat))))
        AND `post_type` = '" . $this->query_data['post_type'] . "'
        AND `post_status` = 'publish'
        WHERE 'price' BETWEEN 'property_min_price' AND 'property_max_price'
        HAVING distance < @distance
        ORDER BY distance\n" . 
        $this->sqlLimit() . ";";
    $this->sql = $sql;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your errors please?

Comment: The form is just not working when i add that line at all.

Comment: you have two where clauses..

Comment: Only one WHERE allowed. Use AND to add your new condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one `WHERE` clause. To add another condition to an existing `WHERE`, use `AND`:

```
... AND `post_status` = 'publish'
    AND `price` BETWEEN 'property_min_price' AND 'property_max_price' ...
```

Also, I guess, back-ticks - not single-quotes - should be used for column names. (But I'm not a MySQL guy, so I'm not sure...)

Comment: $this->query_data['property_min_price'] = get_option['property_min_price'];
        $this->query_data['property_max_price'] = get_option['property_max_price'];
        $this->query_data['price'] = get_option('price');

Comment: Could this be the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that interface, so I can't answer. (I know nothing but SQL...)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would only have one WHERE statement at the end of your SQL string. I noticed you have several joins, followed by a WHERE statement, which is immediately followed by a second WHERE statement.

Have you tried changing your second WHERE to an AND?
        AND `post_status` = 'publish'
        **AND** 'price' BETWEEN 'property_min_price' AND 'property_max_price'

Comment: Could this be the issue: 
 
$this->query_data['property_min_price'] = get_option['property_min_price']; $this->query_data['property_max_price'] = get_option['property_max_price']; $this->query_data['price'] = get_option('price');

Comment: As i have tried using AND instead of WHERE and still have no joy.

Comment: @dmt If query_data['value'] is a key-value array that you have declared elsewhere, and get_option['option_name'] is an option declared in the WordPress file wp-includes/option.php, then it may be the cause of your problems. Have you tried outputting the values of those variables just before creating the SQL string?